# Why does an Exhaust Gas Temperature (EGT) gauge require a power source?

Tags: jet-engine

Why does the EGT gauge on jet engines require bus power if thermoelectric voltages generated by thermocouples are sufficient to move the needles?

Comment: What do you mean by *drive the pointer* ?

Comment: Well if only it's as simple as a thermal couple and a needle. Welcome to 21 century man!

Answer (score 3):

The thermocouple voltage is a DC millivoltage. Presuming you’re talking about an analog gauge, there simply isn’t enough potential to “drive the pointer.” As such, that small voltage is usually amplified. The amplification requires that a larger power supply be used.

For a digital gauge, that millivoltage is capable of being read by a microprocessor, but the rhetorical question of “What powers the microprocessor?” Should be enough to resolve the rest of the question.

Comment: Why _isn't_ there enough potential to drive a (sufficiently-light) pointer?

Comment: I suppose a sufficiently light pointer with sufficiently minimal resistance would work, but I honestly don’t know what those requirements might be. Generally speaking, amplifying if externally gives you more distinct control (and probably accuracy) over something like what you’re suggesting.